# How to truncate a floating number to a number of decimals in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding, truncate

I am a beginner in Python Learning

And I know that this rounds the number instead of truncating:

```
number_float = 14.233677
print(f"{number_float:.3f}")
```

=>This is printing 14.234, BUT I want 14.233

What other function can I use or how can I format this so as it won't round my number?

I tried with this format `:.3f` and i know it is wrong

Comment: For `1.2` (which is actually `1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`) do you want to print `1.199`?

Comment: @Nicoara Antonio, in general, most floating point numbers with a fraction cannot be exactly rounded to N decimal places.  Floating point can encode many, but not all possible decimal values exactly.  14.233 is **not** one of them.  Even if output is text, "14.233", the internal value was more likely 14.233000000000000540012479177676141262054443359375 and what you see is a rounded version of that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the math module,try this:

```
import math

number_float = 14.233677
decimal_places = 3

truncated_number = math.floor(number_float * 10**decimal_places) / 10**decimal_places
print(truncated_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
number_float = 14.233677
str_nb = str(number_float).split('.')
str_nb[1] = str_nb[1][:3]
str_nb = ".".join(str_nb)
print(str_nb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module can help to show what's going on, for example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

number_float = 14.233677

# convert and show full decimal expansion
number_decimal = Decimal(number_float)
print(number_decimal)

# truncate at three decimal digits
trunc_decimal = number_decimal.quantize(Decimal("1e-3"), "ROUND_DOWN")
# convert back to float
trunc_float = float(trunc_decimal)

# output truncated values
print(trunc_decimal, trunc_float)

# how that float value isn't quite right
print(Decimal(trunc_float))
```

An IEEE754 system (i.e. most) will output:

```
14.23367700000000013460521586239337921142578125
14.233 14.233
14.233000000000000540012479177676141262054443359375
```

or you could go with the simple:

```
import math
trunc_float = math.trunc(number_float * 1e3) / 1e3
print(trunc_float, Decimal(trunc_float))
```

notice that this gives **exactly** the same value as via the `decimal` route, but neither float is exactly 14.233.  They're both wrong at around the 16th digit, and I'd suggest reading about the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard to understand why.